# How do I configure to print for a thermal paper printer with react-to-print?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, thermal-printer

I'm working in a React page, and I'm using [react-to-print](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print) for printing. But now I need to print in a thermal paper printer. Those that prints tokens, tickets, etc.

I've already looked over [this question](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/45), but I still don't know which size to set or how to create a size.

And I've already looked over the [source code](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L113), to learn more about the argument **pageStyle** and found this as default:

```
"@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; } @media print { body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } }"
```

But I didn't figured out how to set this argument to print at thermal printer size.

What argument do I pass in pageStyle parameter to print in that size? 

Is there a list of page styles or a way of configuring a new page style?

How do I test this without a printing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: @RahulBhanushali No